# Win32: Is there an equivalent to POSIX sem_init?

Tags: winapi, semaphore

POSIX anonymous semaphores allow me to create and use a semaphore in shared memory. This works great, because this means other processes that shouldn't have access to the semaphore don't have access to the semaphore. In addition, it's easy to incorporate into existing structures.

Does Windows offer something like this? The closest thing I've found is calling `CreateSemaphore` without a name, then having it inherited or `DuplicateHandle()`d to a child.

Edit: @IInspectable wanted me to give context. I'm planning to implement a sort of RPC system through shared memory. The data in shared memory looks like this:

```cpp
struct shm_rpc_block {
  enum rpc_state {
    send = 0,
    receive
  };
  rpc_state state;
  sem_t lock;
  char data[2048 - sizeof(rpc_state) - sizeof(sem_t)];
};
```

The `state` variable begins in the "send" state. Process 1 writes its data to the `data` array, then changes the state to "receive" and unlocks, allowing process 2 to lock. Process 2 reads in the sent data, generates a response, then sends it back. The first process then reads the result, and resets the RPC state to "send".

Comment: Are you trying to solve a particular issue with the [remote procedure call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/rpc-start-page) infrastructure that's already provided by the system?

Comment: That's Windows specific, I'm trying for something portable.

Comment: My project is cross-platform because it's meant to work with a cross-platform emulator. Making it Windows-only would exclude a significant number of MacOS and Linux users.

Comment: @IInspectable LOL: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/xb02es/i_didnt_think_these_kinds_of_people_existed/

Comment: @VictorStafusa-FORABOZO: Awesome, now I'm famous. Or would be, if they weren't shy to disclose my screen name. Though, thanks, I'm going to pass on reading through this. I'm sure the noise would just make my head blow up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NO. You cannot specify a desired starting address for semaphore with **WindowsAPI**.
[The document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsemaphoreexa#remarks) only states three ways to use semaphore between processes. A process can specify the name of a semaphore object in a call to the [OpenSemaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-opensemaphorew) or [CreateSemaphoreEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsemaphoreexa) function besides the two ways you pointed.